# Euler-Lagrange equations for a particle in a system of coordinate caracterised by a metric $g_{ij}$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, metric-tensor, variational-calculus

#### The problem

I'm trying to show that the Euler-Lagrange equations for the Lagrangian $\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2}m(\dot{q} \cdot \dot{q}) - U(q,t)$ can be written as

$$
m \ddot{q}^{l} + m \Gamma^{l}_{ij} \dot{q}^i \dot{q}^j = -g^{kl} U_{,k}
$$

A couple of things to note:

I'm using the notation $U_{,k} \equiv \frac{\partial U}{\partial x^k}$

The metric $g_{ij} = g_{ij}(\vec{x})$ is symmetric (i.e. $g_{ij} = g_{ji}$) and its inverse is $g^{ji}$

The scalar product of the generalized coordinate is $\dot{q} \cdot \dot{q} = g_{ij} \dot{q}^i \dot{q}^j$

#### Tentative of resolution

We know that the Euler-Lagrange equations for a particle $k$ are,

$$
\frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{q}^k} - \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial q^k} = 0
$$

Then calculating the different terms,

$$
 \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial q^k} = \frac{1}{2} g_{ij,k} \dot{q}^i \dot{q}^j - U(q,t)_{,k}
$$

Then, it's where I'm struggling I do not know how deriving

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial{\dot{q}^k}} g_{ij} \dot{q}^i \dot{q}^j
$$

So,
$$
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{q}^k} = ??
$$

Comment: As far as I can see, the derivative in question is just $\dot{q}_k$ (note the lower index), because $g$ is independent of the $\dot{q}^k$ and thus the derivative can be moved past $g$. The Christoffel symbol will then hopefully emerge from the first term of $\partial\mathcal{L}/\partial q^k$.

Comment: @Photon don't forget the factor of 2 - you can hit either $\dot{q}$ with the derivative, not just the first one. And it might be helpful for OP to leave it in the form $g_{kj}\dot{q}^j+g_{ik}\dot{q}^i$.

Comment: The answer is in Schaum's outlines on Vector Analysis pg 205.

Comment: The kinetic terms are and it shows you how to get the Christoffel symbols. If needs be I will supply the answer on Monday as I am a bit busy at the moment.

Comment: @jacob1729 Sure, but by hitting both $\dot q$ you exactly cancel the factor $1/2$ and arrive at $\dot{q}_k$. Of course, you can keep the $q$ with upper indices, but I think, it makes sense to at least combine the two summands to one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've eventually found the answer.

So we have :
$$
\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2} m g_{ij}(\vec{x}(t))\dot{q}^i\dot{q}^j = - U(q,t)
$$

Computing the different terms in Euler-Lagrange equation for a particle $k$:

$$
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{q}^k} = \frac{1}{2}mg_{ij}\dot{q}^i\delta^j_k + \frac{1}{2}mg_{ij}\delta^i_k\dot{q}^j = \frac{1}{2} m g_{ik} \dot{q}^i + \frac{1}{2} g_{kj} \dot{q}^j = m g_{ik} \dot{q}^i
$$

$$
\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{q}^k} = mg_{ik,l} \dot{q}^l \dot{q}^i + mg_{ik} \ddot{q}^i 
$$

$$
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial q^k} = \frac{1}{2}mg_{ij,k}\dot{q}^i\dot{q}^j - U(q,t)_{,k}
$$

Putting these together to construct the Euler-Lagrange equation:
$$
mg_{ik,l} \dot{q}^l \dot{q}^i + mg_{ik} \ddot{q}^i  - \frac{1}{2}mg_{ij,k}\dot{q}^i\dot{q}^j + U(q,t)_{,k} = 0
$$

In the final form, we have $-g^{kl}U_{,k}$ so we observe that it is a good idea to multiply the whole expression by $g^{kl}$:

$$
mg_{ik,l} g^{kl} \dot{q}^l \dot{q}^i + mg_{ik} g^{kl} \ddot{q}^i  - \frac{1}{2}mg_{ij,k} g^{kl} \dot{q}^i\dot{q}^j = -g^{kl} U(q,t)_{,k}
$$

Observing that $g_{ik}g^{kl} = \delta^l_i$ and so $\delta^l_i \ddot{q}^i = \ddot{q}^l$:

$$
m \ddot{q}^l + m g^{kl} \left( g_{ik,l} \dot{q}^l \dot{q}^i  - \frac{1}{2}g_{ij,k} \dot{q}^i\dot{q}^j \right) = -g^{kl} U(q,t)_{,k}
$$

Relabelling dummy indices : $l \rightarrow j$
$$
m \ddot{q}^l + m g^{kl} \left( g_{ik,j} \dot{q}^j \dot{q}^i  - \frac{1}{2}g_{ij,k} \dot{q}^i\dot{q}^j \right) = -g^{kl} U(q,t)_{,k}
$$
$$
m \ddot{q}^l + m g^{kl} \left( g_{ik,j}  - \frac{1}{2}g_{ij,k} \right) \dot{q}^i \dot{q}^j = -g^{kl} U(q,t)_{,k}
$$

Then we observe that :
$$
g_{ik,j} \dot{q}^i \dot{q}^j = \frac{1}{2} g_{ik,j} \dot{q}^i \dot{q}^j + \frac{1}{2} g_{jk,i} \dot{q}^i \dot{q}^j
$$

Where we relabelled $i \rightarrow j$ and $j \rightarrow i$ in the second term, observing that it does not change the implicit sum.

Finally,
$$
m \ddot{q}^l + m g^{kl} \left( \frac{1}{2} g_{ik,j} + \frac{1}{2} g_{jk,i} - \frac{1}{2}g_{ij,k} \right) \dot{q}^i \dot{q}^j = -g^{kl} U(q,t)_{,k}
$$
$$
m \ddot{q}^l + \underbrace{\frac{1}{2} m g^{kl} \left( g_{ik,j} + g_{jk,i} - g_{ij,k} \right)}_{\Gamma^l_{ij}} \dot{q}^i \dot{q}^j = -g^{kl} U(q,t)_{,k}
$$

Comment: Why do you include an explicit time dependence in the potential?

Comment: It was in the statement of the exercise.

Comment: Where was the exercise taken from? I've rarely seen the potential energy function stated as explicitly depending on time. That's not to say that it can't. The energy of the system would not be conserved in such cases though.

Answer (score 0):

A tip: use the Kronecker Delta in the derivative, and remember that the x coordinates are related to the generalized coordinates q, {q^dot}. The delta will basically kill that 1/2 factor, and the Christoffel symbol arises from the corrdinate transformation (parallel transport)